# Event source in asp.net has response with one turn delay

Tags: javascript, asp.net, eventsource

After hours of googling i found only one sample about event source using for asp.net (Not MVC). Firstly i must say i want to learn it and my final goal is to creating a friendly poker website. SignalR is very very good for my purpose but i do not want to use this because i heard:

> SignalR is bad in performance

isn't it?(i hope not). My problem is when server sends response to client it sends the previous text not current:

```
$("#btnListen").click(function ()
        {
            var source = new EventSource('SSEHandler.ashx');
            source.addEventListener("open", function (event)
            {
                $('#headerDiv').append('Latest 5 values');
            }, false);
            source.addEventListener("error", function (event)
            {
                if (event.eventPhase == EventSource.CLOSED)
                {
                    $('#footerDiv').append('Connection Closed!');
                }
            }, false);
            source.addEventListener("message", function (event)
            {
                console.log(event.data);                   
            }, false);
        });
```

And this is SSEHandler:

```
 public class SSEHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }    

     public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpResponse Response;
        Response = context.Response;
        Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream"; 

        Response.Write(string.Format("data: {0}\n\n", "first"));
        Response.Flush(); //client has no response received yet 
        Response.Write(string.Format("data: {0}\n\n", "second"));
        Response.Flush();  //now client get "first".               
        Response.Close();

    }
}
```

After executing this cods client console only have "first". And if i add this to end of SSEHandler:

```
Response.Write(string.Format("data: {0}\n\n", "third"));
Response.Flush();
```

In client console we have "first", "Second".
Thanks for reading my long post.

Comment: try signalR and see if it's fast enough for your project. the code above looks fine, maybe trying a comment before close()ing it...

Comment: Thanks @dandavis. How can i test SignalR for 40 people using it in same time? And could you please more explain for adding comment before close?

Comment: a comment like a keep-alive might cause the client to chow all the sent data. i don't know how to test 40 at once, maybe run 8 tabs on 5 computers?

Comment: Thanks again. Each browser is can be one client(i think and will test). Could you please write your suggested code(keep-alive)?

Comment: print `: keep me alive` after the last message (before close()). use incognito windows to have multiple sessions on one device.

Comment: You should **not** focus on SignalR or any infrastructure concerns, focus on designing your application with enough abstraction and a respect for responsability of each of your objects and you will be able to move away from SignalR or whatever if your project is successful and need to improve its performance.

Comment: Thanks dear Boris. But how can i move away from signalR if it needed? Do you know some better ways for applications based on live connection?

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since you asked the question, but after struggling with this for a while myself I found a workaround I thought could be useful to share for others having the same issue.

Simply adding a comment (line that starts with colon) after each event will make the events appear when they should.

```
Response.Write("data: first\n\n")
Response.Write(":comment\n")
Response.Write("data: second\n\n")
Response.Write(":comment\n")
```

Note: The problem is more apparent when working with events that comes dynamically, since at that point the first event wont produce anything on the client, then when the second event hits, the first is displayed in the client. And this goes on with second and third etc..